# Add session details to controller log methods

Tags: grails

I have a controller where most of the actions require a user to be logged in.  For those actions I want to log in debug mode the user's id in case I need to track down problems a user might be having in production.  For example:

```
def controller {

def action1 {
   log.debug('action1 called for ' + user.id)
   ...
}

def action2 {
   log.debug('action2 called for ' + user.id)
   ...
}
```

That's getting a little redundant.  Is there a way to refactor that so it follows the DRY principle?  I'm using log4j if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [a filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) to apply this behavior across your controller(s). This way you can reuse the filter for multiple controllers or actions.

While the documentation has an example of a logging filter of sorts here is a very simple version that demonstrates the same concept.

```
package com.example
class LoggingFilterExample {
  def filters = {
    all(controller:"*", action:"*") {
      before = {
        log.debug("${controllerName} ${actionName} called for ${session.userid}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good call.  I ended up using request.userPrincipal?.name to show the username from spring security.